# PHP empty $_SERVER array

Tags: php, server

Is it possible to have a php `$_SERVER` variable `NULL`?

When I call `var_dump($_SERVER)`, the result is `NULL`. How it is possible?

But what is the most weird is that this is only after "NON-first" refresh of the page.. I mean:

- edit `somepage.php` on server -> save -> refresh the page -> `$_SERVER` variable is OK (full of data).
- second (third, tenth) refresh (normal/hard...all browsers) -> `$_SERVER` variable is `NULL`

can someone explain this? I have no idea where should I search problem. The page is in reactjs (client-side), but it has nothing to do with this.

UPDATE: server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

Comment: What server are you using (e.g. Apache)?

Comment: Yes, Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

Comment: Can you create a new file that have only var_dump($_SERVER) .. I think you override the variable!

Comment: @MohammadAlabed No problem, but..override the variable...could the problem be in filter_var()? 

$REQUEST_URI = filter_var($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);?

Comment: @MohammadAlabed new file created. Contains only var_dump($_SERVER). First access is OK, second is null

Comment: That makes no sense to me. Don't think you could accomplish that even with `variables_order` shenanigans. Are you checking for other server/PHP errors?

Comment: PHP error log is empty, but I checked apache log and it says:
PHP notice: undefined: variable _SERVER in ....*the file with var_dump($_SERVER); *

Comment: But only on the second request... assuming we can trust what you say :) Would look at PHP's ini. Maybe [variables_order](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order). Anything on Apache end doing stuff with environment variables? You build all this from repository?

Comment: :) trust me. I've googled for apache error in log. **undefined variable _SERVER in...** and voilá: https://odd.blog/2015/02/12/php-notice-undefined-variable-_server-in/

in php.ini there is auto_globals_jit: set on **ON** which causing the problem. When I changed it to **OFF** it started working. But I have no idea about consequences O:)

Answer (score 2):

As it says in [this blog post](https://odd.blog/2015/02/12/php-notice-undefined-variable-_server-in):

In php.ini I had `auto_globals_jit` set to ON which was causing the problem. When I changed it to OFF it started working.

Comment: That is interesting issue :)